# does vulkan bindings have to be sequential in shaders

Tags: glsl, vulkan

is it necessary that bindings for uniforms, varyings or the attributes have to be sequential in vulkan?
Let say we have

```
layout (std140, set = 0, binding = 0) uniform ubo1 {}
layout (std140, set = 0, binding = 3) uniform ubo2 {}
```

is it allowed? same for the attribute bindings.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they don't have to be tightly packed. In the Descriptor Layout description (13.2.1), the spec says:

> Bindings that are not specified have a descriptorCount and stageFlags of zero, and the descriptorType is treated as undefined. However, all binding numbers between 0 and the maximum binding number in the VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo::pBindings array may consume memory in the descriptor set layout even if not all descriptor bindings are used, though it should not consume additional memory from the descriptor pool.
>
> Note: The maximum binding number specified should be as compact as possible to avoid wasted memory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is allowed in shader code. Not so certain about implementations.

You can take a look at the documentation for `VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo` to get an idea of what is involved in defining a descriptor set layout. You'll notice that `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding` allows the specification of a binding at an arbitrary index.

As a matter of personal preference (and that I didn't find any explicit wording on the matter), I simply do not trust implementations to handle this intuitively. So, I create empty bindings to "fill in the gaps".

Comment: I had to empty bindings to remove segfault.